# How to return some variable once in few seconds to client?

Tags: python, loops, timer, tornado, polling

I'm learning python+tornado currently and was stopped with this problem:
i need to write some data one every few sec (for example) to client even using `self.write(var)`

I've tried:

1. `time.sleep` - it's blocked
2. `yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + ...)` - great thing but I still got full request at the end of timeout
3. `.flush` - in some reason it don t want to return Bdata to client
4. `.PeriodicCallback` - browsers window just loading and loading like with another upper methods

I imagine my code like

```
class MaHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        for x in xrange(10):
            self.write(x)
            time.sleep(5) #yes,it's no working
```

That's all. Thanks for any help with this. I'm solving this like 4-5 days and really can't make it by myself.

I still think it can't be done only with server side. It coud be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PeriodicCallback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) class.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self._pcb = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(self._cb, 1000)
        self._pcb.start()

    def _cb(self):
        self.write('Kapooya, Kapooya!')
        self.flush()

    def on_connection_close(self):
        self._pcb.stop()
```

Comment: yes, i've tried it before too. But as another methods that was used - browsers window just loadin' and  loadin' and...to infinity. Still no output like Kapooya, Kapooya! at it :(

Comment: it working great with `print` but i need output it to browser side

Comment: Sorry, I was just going off memory. I have fixed the example by adding `flush` and `on_connection_close`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working as i thought. Still need to close connection with stop button to watch what i got.